# How to merge all `page.items` from `useInfiniteQuery` data.pages hook into a single array?

Tags: arrays, react-hooks, react-query

When using `useInfiniteQuery` hook from `react-query`, we get the `data` as the object below:

https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/infinite-queries

[image]

Basically we get multiple pages inside the `data.pages` property, which is an array of pages.

Each page has an `items` property that contains the array of result items.

I need to merge all those `pages[i].items` in a single array. And I can't be sure upfront how many pages have been fetched.

What is the best practice/pattern for this?

Is this the way to go?

```
const allItems = ([] as Array<ItemType>).concat(...data.pages.map((page) => page.items));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would do:

```
const allItems = data.pages.flatMap(page => page.items)
```

If referential stability is important, wrap that in a `useMemo`:

```
const allItems = React.useMemo(
  () => data.pages.flatMap(page => page.items),
  [data]
)
```

Comment: Hey TkDodo, do you know why is the `allItems` result is not exposed from the `useInfiniteQuery` hook? Isn't this a super common use case? I mean to pass a full list of items to a table/list component? Or maybe should I not be merging it for some reason?

Comment: because you can easily derive it for yourself if you need it :)